# Python flask template inference

Tags: python, html, django-templates, flask-login

I have error in my template when I try to use inheritance block
Everything works before I convert the login.html into html, which is basically everything from base.html

My html files are as below：

base.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
        <title> {% block title %} {% endblock %} | Company Name</title>
        {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>
        {% block body}

        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

login.html :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  <form method="POST">
    <label for="name_question">What is your name? <br>
    <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> <br>
  </form>

  {% if name %}
    <h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
  {% endif %}

{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: What is the problem here? Are you saying that the `extends` tag doesnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing seems wrong with what you are trying to do. This could likely be caused due to a number of other reasons, mainly any of the followings:

- I think that the reference to the base template is relative to you
- TEMPLATE_DIR. Try different things like putting both templates at the
  same level etc.
- Check all the tags in both templates to be sure that they are all
  correctly formatted
- Check the encoding of the files. If it is UTF-8, try to disable the
  BOM in both files.
- Maybe it is a problem with your directory setting. Try to hard code
  the absolute path to check that

My guess would be the final point.

Comment: apparently its because I wrote  {% block body} instead of  {% block body %}. Guess syntax do really screw me up haha